# java.util.NoSuchElementException Reattempt

Tags: java

Ok my first question screwed up please review it now.

This is my error

```
 java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextByte(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextByte(Unknown Source)
at Filename.getMenu(Filename.java:38)
at Filename.main(Filename.java:23)
```

This is my code

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
public class asdasdasd {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        short[] time = {2008, 2009};


        String[] champs = {"Mouths", "Mouths"};

        getMenu(time, champs);
    }

        public static void getMenu(short[] time, String[] champs){
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            byte a;

            do{
                System.out.println("\t\t\tMain Menu");
                System.out.println("Select an Option || Example: Type '1' for Seach\n\n");
                System.out.println("\t\t1.Search\n");
                System.out.print("Input the number: ");
                a = keyboard.nextByte();
                if(a == 1){
                    getSearch(time, champs);
                }
              } while(a < 5);
            keyboard.close();
        }

        public static void getSearch(short[] time, String[] champs){
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            String Team;
            byte b;
            do{
                System.out.print("\n\nEnter the name of the team: ");
                Team = keyboard.next();
                if("Mouths".equals(Team) || "mouths".equals(Team)){
                    Team = "mouths";

                }
                System.out.print("Start a new Search?\nInput 1 for Yes or any other number to return to the main menu: ");
                b = keyboard.nextByte();

            }
            while(b == 1);

            keyboard.close();                                           


        }
    }
```

Ok so basically the input is 1, then mouths, then 2. And then the error came up.

Sorry to everyone who was willing to help and I didn't give much information. I m just scared of getting put down for plagiarism.

I've already been told to use hasNext(), or something like that. Never used it at all and I have no experience What so ever. If someone can show me an example or how to use it in this coding that would be great.

Comment: `hasNextX()` checks if the thing you're about to try to get with `nextX()` exists.

Comment: What line does the error happen on and why do you expect this line to succeed?

Comment: @Sotirios how would I apply that in this code?

Comment: If you entered `mouths` and then pressed enter, since I think `next()` doesn't consume `\n`, `nextByte()` will return the new line.

Comment: @djechlin this line occurs above the if statement  if(a==1)  I expect it to succeed as it has worked the first time, so then it should work the send time when I loop it back to the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because you are calling `keyboard.close()`, and I don't think that you should be doing this.

Before your `getSearch` method exits, you close the scanner you were using.  Calling the [`close` method of the Scanner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()) will also close the stream that the scanner was reading from.  In your case, this is `System.in`.  The next time `getMenu` calls `keyboard.nextByte()`, it asks the scanner it has (not the same one used by `getSearch`) for the next byte.  This scanner is also reading from `System.in`.  However, `System.in` has now been closed, so there will be no next byte to read.  This is why you get a `NoSuchElementException`.

Generally it is good practice to close things that you are finished with.  For example, if you are reading from a file, you should always close the file when you are finished with it. However, you aren't  finished with `System.in` until your program exits, so it would be wrong to close it before this.

At the very least I would remove the call to `keyboard.close()` within `getSearch`.  I also wouldn't worry about closing the scanner at the end of `getMenu`.

Comment: Thank you, I am unsure. I applied both @Harlandraka's advice and yours as well. Seems to working fine now. That was a frustrating 4 hours.

Answer (score 3):

`nextByte()` takes the first byte in the `keyboard` buffer, but it doesn't consume the newline `\n` character, which is taken when `nextByte()` is called for the second time.

You should free the buffer placing a

```
keyboard.nextLine();
```

after

```
keyboard.nextByte();
```

and also after

```
keyboard.next();
```

In order to tell your scanner to directly discard the rest of the line and read from the next line it finds

Comment: I did just as you said and the error still occurred.

Comment: Thanks for the help though. I've read through my textbook and understand what your talking about. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Modify to

```
if(keyboard.hasNextByte()) 
  a = keyboard.nextByte();
```

and

```
 if(keyboard.hasNext())
 Team = keyboard.next();
```

wherever applicable. And clear the buffer of newlines before reading .

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I didn't grasp how to use this properly. Again thanks for your contribution.